# Typescript could be instantiated with a different subtype

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wanted to create a general list component using Typescript in React which forwards props to the underlying component. I tried the following

```
import * as React from "react";

interface BaseProps<TData, TItemProps> {
  Item: React.FC<TItemProps>;
  items: TData[];
}

type Props<TData, TItemProps> = BaseProps<TData, TItemProps> &
  Omit<TItemProps, keyof GeneralItemProps<TData>>;

interface GeneralItemProps<TData> {
  item: TData;
}

export default function GeneralList<
  TData,
  TItemProps extends GeneralItemProps<TData>
>({ Item, items }: Props<TData, TItemProps>): React.ReactElement {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <Item item={item} key={index} />
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

interface ItemProps<TData> extends GeneralItemProps<TData> {
  doStuff: boolean;
}

const MyItem = ({ doStuff, item }: ItemProps<string>) => <p>{item}</p>;
export const MyList = (
  <GeneralList doStuff={true} Item={MyItem} items={["my-string"]} />
);
```

which has the following type error

```
Type '{ item: TData; key: number; }' is not assignable to type 'TItemProps'.
  '{ item: TData; key: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TItemProps', but 'TItemProps' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'GeneralItemProps<TData>'.
```

and cannot grasp why this is?

Btw, the intent is to later allow extend `Props` with `TItemProps` to allow forwarding of custom props to `Item`.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/Gm37Am) suffice for your use cases?  If not, could you elaborate on where it fails with a code example?

Comment: I wanted to use different versions of `Item`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/KwXDkw)

Comment: But that doesn't even work with your original example code, [see here](https://tsplay.dev/zwOkzw).  Seems not particularly related, and if it *is* related, then you probably want to modify your question to spell out that you're trying to get code like in this comment to work and not worry about the implementation error

Comment: Thank for your advice @jcalz, updated the question to better reflect what I was asking for

Comment: I’m really good at typing React components so I can write you an answer in a bit.  There is no relationship between TData and TItemProps in your BaseProps interface.  We need to design this in a way where the Item component is a renderer for an item in your items array, minus the already provided props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problems

#### 1) `Item` component could require extra props

When you say that `TItemProps extends GeneralItemProps<TData>`, it means that `TItemProps`, the props for the `Item` component, must include `{ item: TData }` in its props.  But the `extends` means that it can also require any arbitrary other props.

You've typed your `Props<TData, TItemProps>` to require the extra properties.  Your `GeneralList` correctly complains when `Item={MyItem}` and no `doStuff` prop is passed.  But if you look at the `GeneralList` component you'll see that `doStuff` is not actually passed down to the `Item`!

```
function GeneralList<
  TData,
  TItemProps extends GeneralItemProps<TData>
>({ Item, items, ...props }: Props<TData, TItemProps>): React.ReactElement {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <Item {...props} item={item} key={index} />
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

This is an improvement, but it still gives us a (much more complicated) version of the same error.

> Pick<Props<TData, TItemProps>, Exclude<Exclude<keyof TItemProps, "item">, "Item" | "items">> & { item: TData; key: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TItemProps', but 'TItemProps' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'GeneralItemProps'

#### 2) `Item` component could require a more specific `item`

What happens if your `TItemProps` looks like this?

```
interface ItemProps<TData> extends GeneralItemProps<TData> {
  doStuff: boolean;
  item: TData & {extra: number}
}
```

If `item` is incompatible with `TData` then we get an error in this interface because it doesn't extend `GeneralItemProps<TData>`.  But there is no error if we require that `item` be `TData` *and something else* because the nature of `extends` is that you can always extend with a more specific version.

The above interface doesn't give any (additional) errors but it's a problem.  `TData` and `TItemProps` have no relation in the `BaseProps` interface, so we can't we can't ensure that the `items` in `{ items: TData[] }` have this `extra` prop.  This type of possibility is why you will get errors in the body of your `GeneralList` function component.

#### 3) `Item` component could require an `items` property (or `Item` property)

If `TItemProps` has a property `items` of its own, this is a problem.  We have said that the `GeneralList` props includes a prop `items` of type `TData[]`.  If the `TItemProps` requires anything different than this, then we aren't able to include the extra prop `items={something}` in the same way that we include `doStuff={true}`.

If `TItemProps` just wants to have the same `{items: TData[]}`, that's still a problem because this destructuring `{ Item, items, ...props }` means that the rest object `props` will never have keys `Item` or `items`.

### Solution

#### Work backwards from props

When typescript is trying to see if a `GeneralList` is being called with valid props, the first thing that it sees is the props that you are providing.  So let's work backwards and make the generic variable of a `GeneralList` be the props that it's called with.

We want to ensure that the props always includes an array of `items` and a component `Items`.  I am using `React.ComponentType` instead of `React.FC` to allow both function and class components.

```
function GeneralList<Props extends { Item: React.ComponentType<any>; items: any[] }>(
```

This by itself is obviously not good enough.  We need to ensure that the `Item` component has the right props.  We handle this by saying that the props that you provide must be of type `Prop` *and also* must have a prop `Item` which is a component that takes a specific sets of props which we derive from the other properties of the `Props` type.

We know that the prop `item` on the `Item` should be the type of an element of the array that was provided as `items`: which gives us `{item: Props['items'][number]}`.  This resolves problem #2 explained above.  We are not allowing the `Items` component to determine the `item` type on its own.  We are requiring that the `Item` component matches the `items` that we have.

We know that the `Item` component will get all of the other props that we provided.  Everything except for `items` and the `Item` itself which are destructured out.  That is `Omit<Props, 'Item' | 'items'>`.  Typing `Item` as a component of `Props` resolves problem #1 while omitting the specific problematic props resolves problem #3.  You will not be able to call `GeneralList` with an `Item` component that requires a prop `items` or `Item`.

```
function GeneralList<Props extends { Item: React.ComponentType<any>; items: any[] }>(
    { Item, items, ...props }: Props & { Item: React.ComponentType<Omit<Props, 'Item' | 'items'> & { item: Props['items'][number] }> }
): React.ReactElement {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {items.map((item, index) => (
                <Item key={index} {...props} item={item} />
            ))}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

#### Testing

We know that we want the following cases to work, and they do!

```
const MyItemString = ({ doStuff, item }: ItemProps<string>) => <p>{item}</p>;
const MyItemNumber = ({ doStuff, item }: ItemProps<number>) => <p>{item}</p>;
```

```
<GeneralList doStuff={true} Item={MyItemString} items={["my-string"]} /> // ok
<GeneralList doStuff={true} Item={MyItemNumber} items={[5]} /> // ok
```

We don't get any error from providing extra unneeded props, which is good.

```
<GeneralList doStuff={true} doOtherStuff={true} Item={MyItemString} items={["my-string"]} /> // ok
```

Let's make sure that we get appropriate errors on wrong props.  The error message is always on the `Item` prop and it can be convoluted and hard to read, but we *are* getting errors.

```
// error due to string/number mismatch
<GeneralList doStuff={true} Item={MyItemNumber} items={["my-string"]} /> // error
<GeneralList doStuff={true} Item={MyItemString} items={[5]} /> // error
<GeneralList doStuff={true} Item={MyItemString} items={[5, "my-string"]} /> // error

// error because doStuff not provided
<GeneralList Item={MyItemString} items={["my-string"]} /> // error

// error because we can't require `item` as a prop
const RequiresPropItems = ({ item, items }: { item: string; items: string[] }) => <p>{item}</p>;
<GeneralList Item={RequiresPropItems} items={["my-string"]} /> // error
```

You can test it out in the [Typescript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/4w1ZyN)